# Heroku CLI Hangs After I Log In

Tags: heroku, windows-10, git-bash, heroku-cli

I am on Windows 10 and I use Git Bash to use the Heroku CLI. I've used it before with no problems. Just today after a month of not using it I realize that the Password won't hide anymore. I'm positive this is not normal because the docs show it isn't, plus, displaying passwords is always a no-no. Then when I login, it says "Logged In as *******@email.com" but won't do anything else. The cursor is just flashing and won't bring me to a new line. What's going on?!

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: So I tried it in the new Windows Terminal (Powershell) and it works! Seems like something is wrong with Git Bash. I'll go ahead and reinstall.